# Interior, closure, boundary of countable complement topology

Tags: general-topology

I've been set the following question

[image: Questions]

I started by trying to work out the interior, but I couldn't get any further. I'm using the definition that the interior of a set $A$  w.r.t. a topological space $X$ is the set of all $x\in X$ such that there exists a open $U$ such that $x\in U\subset A$. Clearly the interior of $A$ is always contained in $A$, so I'm trying to find which $U\subset A$ are open, and then points that are contained by the union of these open sets contained in $A$ form the interior. How do I know whether there will be an open set $U$ contained in $A$? I'm completely lost! Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a typo in the question. It should read:

> $Int(A)=\begin{cases}
> A, &\text{ if $X\setminus A$ is at most countable}\\
> \varnothing, &\text{ if $X\setminus A$ is uncountable}&
> \end{cases}
> $

Actually this is dual to the closure $\overline A$, since the interior of $A$ is the complement of the closure of $X\setminus A$.

To find the conditions under which $A$ has an interior, just assume that there exists an open non-empty set $U$ which is a subset of $A$. Then $X\setminus U$ is at most countable, and so is $X\setminus A$. But what does this mean for the openness of $A$ itself?

Comment: Oh so then $A$ is open and as $A\subseteq A$ every point $x\in A$ is in the interior?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So we can say that if $A$ has a non-empty interior, then $A$ is itself open. Note that sometimes is more convenient to use the characterisation of $Int (A)$ as the union of all open sets contained in $A$, that is the largest open subset of $A$.